# Purpose of /proc/thread-self?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, proc

I'm fairly new to Linux OS programming world. I'm working on a project to control Intel CPU (turbo boost, hyper threading, min & max scaling frequencies to solve problems for other users). Whilst investigating `/proc/stat` for CPU utilization I stumbled across this:

```
$ ll /proc/thread-self
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 22 04:26 /proc/thread-self -> 9389/task/9389/

$ ll /proc/self
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 22 04:26 /proc/self -> 29420/

$ ll /proc/self
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 22 04:26 /proc/self -> 29636/

$ ll /proc/thread-self
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 22 04:26 /proc/thread-self -> 30021/task/30021/
```

`thread-self` and `self` are constantly changing every time you list the symbolic links with `ll`. The date and time remain at the last boot time though.

I did a little digging and found this [email chain in 2014](https://lwn.net/Articles/607422/):

> This patchset implements `/proc/thread-self` a magic symlink that solves
>   a couple of problems.

.... further down the email says:

> ```
>   proc: Have net show up under /proc/<tgid>/task/<tid>
>   proc: Implement /proc/thread-self to point at the directory of the current thread
>   proc: Point /proc/net at /proc/thread-self/net instead of /proc/self/net
>   proc: Point /proc/mounts at /proc/thread-self/mounts instead of /proc/self/mounts
> ```

How dp the symbolic link(s) work? Or how do we use them for meaningful analysis/display of what Linux is doing? Or are they simply meaningless and to be ignored as "fluff"?

Answer (score 5):

`/proc/self` is a symlink to the current process, the `ls` process in your examples. Since each `ll` spawns a new `ls` process with a different PID the symlink changes each time. It's a magic symlink that changes based on which process accesses it. Different processes will see different destinations.

`/proc/thread-self` is the same thing except it points to the current thread instead of the current process. In the output you show, `ls` is looking up the symlink on its main (and probably only) thread, so the thread ID matches the process ID.

If you check the output of `mount` or `cat /proc/mounts` you'll see how this "magic" is implemented. `/proc` is typically mounted as a virtual filesystem.

```
$ mount | grep proc
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
```

Any time you access an entry under `/proc` the [`proc` filesystem](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html) handles the lookup. In contrast to standard filesystems like `ext4`, `xfs`, or `tmpfs`, there is no underlying set of files on disk. Instead, there is a kernel level driver that handles all the filesystem calls. When you access `/proc/self` the kernel driver checks what process is making the request and dynamically crafts a symlink pointing to that processes's PID.

What use is it? Well, there's a lot of information under `/proc/<PID>`. For example, you can look in `/proc/<PID>/fd/*` to see what file descriptors a process has open.  `/proc/<PID>/cmdline` gives the the contents of `argv`. `/proc/<PID>/status` has a bunch of information including uid, gid, and memory usage. You might, for instance, insert a call to `ls -l /proc/self/fd/` when debugging file descriptor leaks.

Comment: So it's like an `echo $$` which `ls` can use for finding out it's own PID but which I can do from outside? I guess I won't be using `/proc/self` anytime soon then.